# MS SQL Server on Linux: set password using script

Tags: sql-server, linux, bash, sql-server-ce, mssql-jdbc

I have installed MSSQL Server 2017 on Ubuntu 16.04.
Now, I must change password.
I know that I can change password using the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl stop mssql-server
sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-sa-password
```

But! I need to change password via script.
Ok. To solve this problem, I had installed "expect" and had wrote script:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/bin/expect <<EOD
spawn sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-sa-password
expect "password:"
send "Pa$$wo4d!\r"
expect "password:"
send "Pa$$wo4d!\r"
interact
EOD
```

Double password - password+confirmation.
I have run the script:

```
ubuntu:~# bash 1.sh
spawn sudo /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-sa-password
Enter the SQL Server system administrator password:
Confirm the SQL Server system administrator password:
```

But it does not work. When I try to connect to mssql server, I got an error:

```
ubuntu:~# /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -U SA -P Pa$$wo4d!
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Login failed for user 'SA'..
```

OK, let's try a Windows authorization:

```
ubuntu:~#  /opt/mssql-tools/bin/sqlcmd -S localhost -E -C
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : SSPI Provider: No 
Kerberos credentials available.
Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server : Cannot generate SSPI context.
```

I can't connect to MSSQL Server until I change my password!

And!

I need to change password via script only.
Can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 3):

More easiest way:

```
sudo MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=${Password} /opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-sa-password
```

Answer (score 1):

Solve the problem via script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import pexpect
ssh_cmd = '/opt/mssql/bin/mssql-conf set-sa-password'
timeout=30
child = pexpect.spawn(ssh_cmd, timeout=timeout)
child.expect(['password:'])
child.sendline('Pa$$wo4d!')
child.expect(['password:'])
child.sendline('Pa$$wo4d!')
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
child.close()

if 0 != child.exitstatus:
    raise Exception(stdout)
```